# diff marked files in Dired+

Tags: dired, diff

If I have marked a couple files in different directories using [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) is there a way to see the `diff`?  I was looking at `dired-diff` and `diredp-diff`, but they both take the file at point.  Granted that isn't a whole lot harder, but I was wondering if there is a way to mark the files first and diff them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. But be clear about what you are trying to diff. Do you want to compare each marked file in one dir with some marked file in the other dir? Or do you want to compare the directory listings and not the file contents? Not clear.

If you just want to compare directory listings, and you want to compare only the listings of the marked files, then you can do that by using command `diredp-marked` to show only the marked files in a Dired buffer.  Do that for both Dired buffers, and then use command `ediff-buffers` to compare those listings.

(Command `diredp-marked-other-window` is bound to `C-M-*`.)

Comment: I don't have an answer for diffing the contents of two sets of files. Hopefully someone else will. If you indicate the files to diff using Dired then presumably the files to be compared would have the same names in each directory. Otherwise, you will need some way to pair them off, for diffing.

Comment: yes, that is exactly right, I am trying to get a handle on dired -- I imagine I could easily extend it do this when I understand it better